# PostgreSQL connecting and disconnecting on each query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

How should I use postgresql? Should I just connect to db once when the app is starting and stay connected or connect/disconnect on each query?

The problem I have when I stay connected is that after some time it will always throw me this error: `"Error: read ECONNRESET"` .

Basicly I do this:

```
db.connect(); //in there I create pg.client and connect to db
```

and than I just do normal `db.client.query()`, but that after some time throws the error, so should I on each query do `connect()` and after it `disconnect()` - `client.end()`?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing to "stay connected" to a database in your scenario, but I think what you mean to refer to is a keep-alive. You should be able to implement this manually by doing a simple select query that returns a small piece of data every so often so that the connection doesn't time-out. The query doesn't even have to actually do any real work, you can use the select statement like a ping.

Comment: how often should I do that?

Comment: Go to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html and scroll down to tcp_keepalives_idle to see what I'm referring to then check or change the setting on your sql server.

Comment: Actually that might not be the greatest reference after actually looking at it. There should be some sort of connection timeout setting somewhere that you can look at. You should also just try running the query at an interval that you know should work. 30 seconds sounds like a reasonable interval to me.